# Line chart is going blank (showing large red x)

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Hi i am using dynamic line graph chart to display some random floating values.

The Line graph displaying chart will become like this image after some time of displaying line graph:

[image: Chart area displaying like this]

This is my code to add the used to update the graph values:

```
series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
series1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
series1.MarkerSize = 5;
series1.MarkerStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Circle;
series1.Name = deviceid;                                  
chart1.Series.Add(series1);
series1.ToolTip = "Name";

series1.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), po);// po will have some floating point value
double removeBefore = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((double)(4) * (-1)).ToOADate();

while (series1.Points[0].XValue < removeBefore)
{
    series1.Points.RemoveAt(0);
}
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = series1.Points[0].XValue;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(series1.Points[0].XValue).AddSeconds(5).ToOADate();
chart1.Invalidate();
series1.Name = "Name";
```

Comment: series1.Name = deviceid; //deviceid will have some name

Comment: Is this in a loop? timed?

Comment: Did you ask a question?

Comment: I put the lines from Point.AddXY to Invalidate into  a timed loop and it runs without any problems for hours. If there are problems they are not in the code shown.

Comment: The big red X of doom is the chart's way of signifying a problem during `Paint`ing or another `Exception`. If the axis min is greater than the max, trying to remove points that don't exist....those can all cause the big red X. Without knowing more, can't offer any specific solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and also I am running that function that display graph in a thread is that causing a problem. Should i Check for illegal cross threading like in the case of a text box. to prevent

Comment: Is there any explicit exception that needed to be handled because I tried using generic exception handler which dint show any exception when the above error occurred.

Comment: It's not always an exception, but sometimes just a problem during painting (like if the axis min is greater than the max). They are sometimes very hard to diagnose. You definitely should handle threading issues, though that may not be the root cause. Where does your data (the `po` values) come from? And, answer the other comments about where this code runs - in a loop, in a timer, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Bit late for this problem but may help someone else:
Trailing spaces on a series name will cause a "Cross", so in this case, if deviceid was "1 " rather than "1" then the chart will not display